# Determine shortest time frame

Tags: algorithm, sorting, date-sorting

Is there an algorithm for determining the shortest timeframe in which one could see a baseball game at each stadium. Is there also a way to specify a travel path, the order in which I visit stadiums? I have provided a google doc listing days each California MLB team has a home game for May 2016.

[2016 CA MLB May Home Games](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_YT6cAVy0GrjDhxSBOZT-p5kqWS9mtxTZg85hbDRYjM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This seems like a variation of the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: With only five teams, you should be able to come up with an answer by hand with a few minutes' work. Or, if you want the absolute best possible (shortest time frame or distance traveled), you could easily write a program to do an exhaustive search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you task about is the Traveling Salesman Problem. I will not provide the full answer as this is a homework but you can start looking at:

1. Depth first search
2. Breadth first search

These are searching algorithm that will check every possible node and vertices. With the correct implementation you can use this solution be check every possible station with a "distance".